# Why is it not possible to use imports via {..} notation as type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I'm importing a TypeScript type via

```
import {BrowserWindow} from 'electron';
```

Afterwards it is not possible to use it as a type, but I can create a new Object:

```
let myVar: BrowserWindow = null; //not working. Error: TS2304: Cannot find name 'BrowserWindow'.
let myVar2 = new BrowserWindow(); // working
```

Why does TypeScript behave this way?

This is workaround, but I don't understand why my first approach is not working:

```
import BrowserWindow = Electron.BrowserWindow;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'not working', because it looks fine to me.

Comment: I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: It depends how the class is defined in the definition file